# Get multiplicity of zeros in sympy?

Tags: sympy, zerocrossing

I would like to get the multiplicity of zeros as a return value from `sympy.solveset`.
For the example below I get `zeroes = {0}`. I would like to receive something like
`zeroes = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. Thanks!

```
import sympy

z = sympy.symbols('z')
zeroes = sympy.solveset(sympy.Eq(z**6, 0), z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `roots` instead:

```py
import sympy

z = sympy.symbols('z')
zeroes = sympy.roots(sympy.Eq(z**6, 0), z)

print(zeroes)
```

This prints:

```
{0: 6}
```

Comment: No need to use `Eq`. Also `roots(z**6, multiple=True)` gives the roots with multiplicity as a list.